# Bionic toolchain ld relocatable object file issue

Tags: android, arm, cross-compiling, grpc, bionic

I'm trying to cross-compile for Arm-android the GRPC C++, during the linking of some libraries I've got these errors from ld:

```
    arm-linux-androideabi-ld: error: /grpc/objs/opt/src/cpp/client/client_context.o: requires unsupported dynamic reloc R_ARM_REL32; recompile with -fPIC
    arm-linux-androideabi-ld: error: /grpc/objs/opt/src/cpp/server/server.o: requires unsupported dynamic reloc R_ARM_REL32; recompile with -fPIC
    arm-linux-androideabi-ld: error: /grpc/objs/opt/src/cpp/util/status.o: requires unsupported dynamic reloc R_ARM_REL32; recompile with -fPIC
    src/cpp/client/client_context.cc:55: error: undefined reference to '__dso_handle'
    include/grpc++/impl/codegen/status.h:53: error: undefined reference to '__dso_handle'
    include/grpc++/impl/grpc_library.h:61: error: undefined reference to '__dso_handle'
```

Does anyone know what is the cause of this error? The .cc files are all compiled with the `-fPIC` flag.